# Can a Microsoft Access Database save incorrectly if multiple computers are updating the same field?

Tags: java, microsoft-access, sql

If I make a program in java that constantly requests and saves data every time you click on a button, and I install this program on 30+- computers, every program will save to one Microsoft access database stored on a server all accounts will have access to, the function of the program is to get the amount of "clicks" on a specific field of the active user, and when the user clicks again, it adds one to that number and saves it again using SQL

So the question is, Is there a possibility that the numbers could become inaccurate?

Example of the database

Name       Surname       Clicks

James      Smith           5

John       Argh            25

Now 30 computers within 5-10 seconds all sends an instruction to get and add 1 to the Clicks field where the name is John and Surname is Argh, Will there be any problems of it reading incorrect data or not saving accurate data? Or Will it work correctly and save the data accurately

For example

John       Argh            55

This is a small project for my school that everyone will be using, I'm just worried that there might be incorrect data saved, Its highly important that this data is accurate if there is a problem with it being inaccurate, in what way can I make it to where it does, in fact, save accurately. I'm fairly sure it should count the "clicks" correctly due to how SQL works, just thought I'd double check by asking on here.

Comment: A Microsoft Access database isn't really designed to be used in the way your using it.  However, I know nothing about your application design, but questions how to implement something like this would be out of scope anyway

Comment: "Its highly important that this data is accurate" - Sounds like you should be using SQL instead of Access.

Comment: SQL Statements in Java updates the "Clicks" My question is, are the updates Instant? or is there a delay that can cause incorrect updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.

If you have one MDB file, and you open it as one user, you lock the database.

If you use it as a server application, and you use an external source to connect to the MDB, then the server version of the MDB will handle the saving.

The only thing that you will get is that the saves are queued, and that could potentially lead to someone overwriting someone elses data without them seeing what was updated in the meanwhile.

This means that you will need to add logic to prevent this or people will be able to update the same field without knowing that someone else updated it with something while they did.

The easiest solution to do this is by sending a from and to to the server, so it can see if the from data is still the same and reject with reason if it is newer, so the enduser can see that the field was updated in the meanwhile.

Comment: The file never gets opened, SQL Statements in Java updates the "Clicks"  So all those computers will still have access to save to it at the same time right?

Comment: the only thing that will happen really is it updating the clicks field and adding one to the existing number, that's all I'm worried about, that the data gets updated to fast with SQL therefore leading to inaccurate results, but if it has somewhat of a delay, it seems there should be no problem.

Comment: If 2 users click at the same time, and their old value is 5, both may want to change that to 6. If your query just does: update that value by 1 regardless of what it was, then you are fine, and it will work.